# Geographic Position and Iterations on cameras Web Scraping a Traffic Camera Map

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape data from this traffic camera map:

https://traffic.houstontranstar.org/layers/layers_ve.aspx?&inc=true&rc=true&lc=false&cam=true&dms=false&spd=true&tr=false&wthr=false&rfw=true&rm=false&nml=false&nmd=false

This is what it looks like: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCbvw.jpg)

The map shows the positions of a bunch of traffic cameras with these camera icons: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFgXq.png)

I am currently able to manually inspect element at each camera location and get the source link for the image in the camera's video feed. For example, I can get this link here for an example camera: https://www.houstontranstar.org/snapshots/cctv/913.jpg?arg=1661886693594

However, I also need to get the location of these cameras. Does anyone know if there is a way for me to get some sense of geographic location of these cameras on the map?

The second question I had was that if anyone knew of a good way for me to iterate upon the cameras? I'm completely new to web scraping so am currently just inspecting the elements of the website manually and going from there.

Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is one way of obtaining those cameras locations (lat/lon):

import requests
import pandas as pd

```
url = 'https://traffic.houstontranstar.org/data/layers/cctvSnapshots_json.js?arg=1661888238910'
r = requests.get(url)
df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()['cameras'])
print(df)
```

This returns a dataframe with 1126 rows × 8 columns:

|  | location | id | lat | lng | dir | fc | fp | url |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 EAST @ SAN JACINTO | 1002 | 29.7682 | -95.3557 | South | 6 | 300 | showWin('/layers/gc.aspx?cam=1002&loc=IH-10_East_at_SAN_JACINTO') |
| 1 | 10 EAST @ SAN JACINTO (E) | 1003 | 29.7698 | -95.3505 | South | 1 | 0 | showWin('/layers/gc.aspx?cam=1003&loc=IH-10_East_at_SAN_JACINTO_(E)') |
| 2 | 10 EAST @ JENSEN | 1004 | 29.7703 | -95.3437 | North | 1 | 0 | showWin('/layers/gc.aspx?cam=1004&loc=IH-10_East_at_JENSEN') |
| 3 | 10 East @ Gregg | 1005 | 29.7699 | -95.3357 | North | 1 | 0 | showWin('/layers/gc.aspx?cam=1005&loc=IH-10_East_at_Gregg') |
| 4 | 10 East @ Waco | 1006 | 29.7729 | -95.3246 | North | 1 | 0 | showWin('/layers/gc.aspx?cam=1006&loc=IH-10_East_at_Waco') |

[...]

Comment: 1+ back now ;))

Comment: LOL thanks @Prophet. But I genuinely thought your answer was better (not the first time even), and I upvoted it. Also, to avoid any misunderstanding with the OP (enough times the lesser answer gets accepted, as you know), I removed my answer. I didn't do it to get upvoted back. of course, don't go now and  retract it :)

Comment: I know, but I still think it's a nice way to give back. especially since it doesn't cost money ;)

Comment: @platipus_on_fire  could you give me some intuition as to how you found out the data is stored at that link? I need to do this for another similar map in another city (and will probably need to do it a few times more) so I would like to learn how the technology works broadly.

Comment: @Prophet just pinging you as well as I'm not sure who came up with the solution / hoping one of you sees this

Comment: @Argov it's completely platipus_on_fire. I just came here to talk with him about some other issue, not your question. I'm sorry :)

Comment: @Argov: that link is the API accessed by javascript in page, to pull down data about cameras. You can see this by opening Dev tools - Network tab, and inspecting the network calls made (XHR). Sorry for not clarifying it from the beginning, I thought it will be straightforward for you considering you mentioned you inspected the page structure. There is no guarantee that a different website will have the same logic in pulling/displaying the data. You can always add another question, if you have difficulties with a different website.

Comment: @platipus_on_fire thanks for the information! LOL so my competency with this kind of stuff is clicking inspect element and checking random links I see in the source code and hoping it works out. hmm yeah I'm not sure if this is the same logic for these other two maps I'm looking at in NYC and Boston: https://webcams.nyctmc.org/ and https://www.mass.gov/info-details/massachusetts-traffic-map. Would you be able to help find me a similar kind of dataframe for these two cities?

Comment: @Argov I will gladly help you, however: try and apply what you learn from this one. If you cannot, ask a new question, showing what you have tried and doesn't work for the new url. Me or someone else will respond.